# Using BLE/USB camera/barcode reader in React Native App

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to make a react native app, which connects to an external Barcode Reader/Camera for scanning barcodes. I know that it is easy to implement using react-native-camera but I need to connect it so an external device. Any idea how we could implement it?

Comment: if you are using an android scanner, after focusing on text-input and press scanner enter, it will scan automatically(barcodes data appear into text-input). If you are using android tablet, android phone or ios just attach the scanner, open your react native app scan it, it will scan automatically after focusing on text-input, text-input keypress event will fire automatically. if you don't understand let me know and share your code.

Comment: Can u share code with me?

Comment: Have you achieved in react native?

@ShashwatMDas ?